# Match Image from a Collection of Image

Tags: image, opencv, matching, surf

I have to match Image with a collection of Image. I will scan the Image from camera and then it will search from the collection. I am using SURF algo of OpenCV. For a single Image it is working fine. I made a loop to search from the collection, but it is taking so much time to produce result. Please help me.

Comment: Search for bag of words.

Comment: is exactly the same image in your collection, or might there be differing compression artifacts, slighter position changes, different lighting, different appearences, different background, etc? I think your task isn't clear.

Comment: Create an index, train it, and then using knnMatch method, find matching keypoints. Apply filtering on matched keypoints, to weed out false positives, using Lowe's ratio method.

Comment: #Chrono Trigger --- Can bag of words will work for an iPhone Application.

Comment: #Micka --- Either the Image will blur or having different color it should match if the appearance of that image will be there. if the background is different definitely that image will not come as output.

Comment: #bad_keypoints -- actually how to provide index , i didn't found yet. currently in search I also found that if I will store the keypoints and descriptors of the image it will match faster . But in iOS I am not finding any way to store these.